# Is it possible to restore a SQL Server database (or a single table) from backup to Databricks Delta table?

Tags: sql-server, databricks, database-backups, azure-databricks, delta-lake

We are planning to migrate some archive SQL Server tables to Databricks Delta tables. Since these are archive and might not change frequently, we thought it might be better to restore them from backup instead of connecting directly through JDBC connector. Is it possible to restore a database backup taken in SQL Server into Databricks Delta database / tables? If so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to restore a database backup taken in SQL Server into Databricks Delta database / tables?

That is not possible.  Spark cannot read SQL Server database backup files.  The only thing you can do with a SQL Server database backup is restore it on a running SQL Server instance.